# There always exists a finite, increasing chain of R-submodules of M isomorphic to R/P. Can we describe P?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

So I've been studying some commutative algebra and I came across the following theorem

> **Theorem :** Let R be a Noetherian ring. Let $M$ be a non trivial $R$-module, finite over $R$. There exists a chain of $R$-submodules of $M$
>   $$ 0 \neq M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \cdots \subset M_n = M $$
>   such that $ M_i / M_{i-1} \simeq R/ P_i $ for some $P_i \in\mathrm{Spec}(R).$

Now let $\mathcal{P} = \{ P_1,...,P_n \}$, with $P_i$ as defined above. Then shortly after the theorem there was this corollary

> **Corollary :** $\mathrm{Ass}_R (M) \subseteq \mathcal{P}$.

I think, however, that the two sets are not always equal. My question is, assuming there exists $  P_i \notin \mathrm{Ass}_R (M) $, what is that $P_i$'s relation to $M$? Is it possible for such a $P_i$ to exist? I mean it cannot be random but how can I find a description of $\mathcal{P}$?

Could someone please provide an intuitive idea and a book I could find that stuff?

Comment: As far as i know the chain of submodules is finite if $M$ is finite over $R$; you are not mentioning this. Second, the inclusion that i know of is $\mathcal{P} \subset Assc_R(M)$ and not the other way as you have written. Which book are you studying from?

Comment: @Manos M should be finite over R i just forgot it. I am studying some lecture notes that is why i asked for book references. As for the inclusion, I found it as a corollary in a proposition saying that $Ass_R(M)$ is finite. It was proven that $Ass_R(M) \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ therefore it should be finite.

Answer (score 1):

The chain in the theorem is an existence theorem and there is no uniqueness. As an example, let $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathrm{Ass}(M)=\{0\}$. But, we can write the chain $p\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ for any prime $p$ and we have $\mathcal{P}=\{0,p\mathbb{Z}\}$. In particular, the primes occurring in $\mathcal{P}$ can be fairly arbitrary.

Comment: could you give an example where M is not the ring?

Comment: Am not sure what you really want. Take $M=R^2$ and the chain $pR^2\subset R^2$.